# How to configure jasper/jrxmo report and viewResolver in Spring MVC with Tiles

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, tiles

I am new in spring configuration with jasper report , 
I have a problem calling the correct file for my jrxml when I setup the tiles configuration.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver ();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

when calling the the file. it append .jsp to the end of the file.

I tried this one but still not doesnt work :

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

@Bean
public XmlViewResolver getXmlViewResolver() {
    XmlViewResolver resolver = new XmlViewResolver();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:reports/testReport1.jrxml");
    resolver.setLocation(resource);
    resolver.setOrder(0);
    return resolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Bean
public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
    JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("resources/jasperreports/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
    resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
    resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"Report_*"});
    resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
    resolver.setOrder(0);
    return resolver;
}
```

Where:

"resources/jasperreports/" is the folder where you have all your reports.

".jasper" is the the extension of compilled jasper report.

new String[] {"Report_*"} is the prefix of the jasper reports.